# Is there any open source IDE written in C/C++ , which preferbly uses Qt and has plugin support like eclipse?

Tags: ide

Is there any open source IDE written in C/C++ , which preferably uses Qt and has plugin support like eclipse?

Comment: Qt Creator ! (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Creator_Plug-in_Contribution_Guide)

Answer (score 3):

KDevelop is Qt+KDE based.

Answer (score 2):

There is for example [MonkeyStudio](http://www.monkeystudio.org/).

Comment: But it doesn't have plugin support.